# Order of execution of .cshrc and .login

Tags: shell, csh

After extensive research, I read that on login, the login shell executes the .cshrc and the .login files in my home directory. But the order of execution depends on the shell programme. How do I find the correct order of execution of the above scripts for my machine? Running the shell on a AIX machine

Comment: Put an echo statement like `echo .login` or `echo .cshrc` in both and log in.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [What "dot" files do the various shells use?](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part5/section-6.html):

```
  csh
      Some versions have system-wide .cshrc and .login files.  Every
      version puts them in different places.

      Start-up (in this order):
          .cshrc   - always; unless the -f option is used.
          .login   - login shells.
```

(Additionally, `.login` is executed only one during a session.  `.cshrc` is executed upon starting an instance of the shell.)